# A website with black background if the time is 21-09 and white otherwise

Tags: javascript, html

I need a website with black background if the time is between 21 and 09 and white otherwise, how do I make it do that according to the clock?

So now I got this :

```html
<html>

<head>
  <title></title>
</head>

<body>

</body>
<script type="text/javascript">
  var currentTime = Date().getHours();
  //var currentTime = new Date().getMinutes();
  console.log(currentTime);
  if (currentTime <= 20 && currentTime <= 9) {
    document.body.style.backgroundColor = "#000"
  } else {
    document.body.style.backgroundColor = "#fff";
  }
</script>

</html>
```

But still doesn't work, I believe something is wrong with the `if` elements, any tips?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You should show a minimum effort understanding what you are doing and [researching similar questions](http://idownvotedbecau.se/noresearch) in Stack Overflow before [asking your own question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow, please read: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve Note that Stackoverflow is not a coding service. We expect you to have attempted something, and then provide a question concerning any problems you ran into during those attempts.

Comment: I would look into setting timezones and date functions in php. I would then look into javascript and css to apply the colors to my background element.

Comment: @Martin I have not yet gotten to the point in my studies where i use php

Comment: `currentTime <= 20` would be true if `currentTime` smaller or equal to `20` but you want to makc the background back if `currentTime` is larger or equal to `20`, so it has to be  `currentTime >= 20`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```html
<html>

<head>
  <title></title>
</head>

<body>

</body>
<script type="text/javascript">
  var currentTime = (new Date()).getHours();
  //var currentTime = new Date().getMinutes();
  console.log(currentTime);
  if (currentTime <= 20 && currentTime <= 9) {
    document.body.style.backgroundColor = "#000"
  } else {
    document.body.style.backgroundColor = "#fff";
  }
</script>

</html>
```